# Dialogflow - Knowledge base is not working in detect intents API

Tags: ruby, dialogflow-es

I've created a knowledge base in Dialogflow and it's working fine in the simulator, but it's not working using the api, I'm working with Ruby and using the V2 (I couldn't find V2beta1 for Ruby).

this is my code:

```
client = ::Google::Cloud::Dialogflow::V2::Sessions::Client.new
session = "projects/#{project_id}/agent/sessions/#{session_id}"
query_input = { text: { text: message, language_code: 'en-US' } }
query_params = { knowledge_base_names: ["projects/#{project_id}/knowledgeBases/#{knowledge_base_id}"]}
client.detect_intent session: session, query_input: query_input, query_params: query_params
```

When I've added the `query_params` and `knowledge_base_id`, I got this error:

> Unknown field name 'knowledgeBaseNames' in initialization map entry.

I need a way to use the knowledge base via the api.